# Best way to compare .NET enum values

Tags: .net, enums, compare

What's the best way in code to compare enum values?  For example, if I have the following enum type:

```
public enum Level : short {
    Low,   
    FairlyLow,
    QuiteLow,
    NotReallyLow,
    GettingHigh,
    PrettyHigh,
    High,
    VeryHigh,
}
```

And I want to be able to write statements such as:

```
from v in values select v where v > Level.QuiteLow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You need to cast the enum value to its numeric value, because enum values aren't comparable :</strike>

```
from v in values where (short)v > (short)Level.QuiteLow select v
```

EDIT: actually this is not true : enum values *are* comparable, so this code works fine :

```
from v in values where v > Level.QuiteLow select v
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was mostly checking that there wasn't a better (or other) way of doing this.  I also padded out the enum values a bit:

public enum Level : short {
    Low = 1,   
    FairlyLow = 5,
    QuiteLow = 10,
    NotReallyLow = 15,
    GettingHigh = 20,
    PrettyHigh = 30,
    High = 40,
    VeryHigh = 60,
}

Comment: I can't imagine any better way, this one seems optimal to me ;)

Comment: Please note though that this depends on the ordering of the enum values, IE if QuiteLow and NotReallyLow were swapped then it would improperly compare values.

Comment: which is, in-part, why I padded out the values... so that new items can be inserted without disrupting the order or the numerical values.